# Why do you need to make sure the eigen vectors are orthonormal when trying to diagonalise a hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In an answer to this question I asked:[Issue finding a unitary matrix which diagonalizes a Hermitian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207858/issue-finding-a-unitary-matrix-which-diagonalizes-a-hermitian), it was said that without normalising my eigen vectors I wouldn't get the corresponding diagonal matrix containing the eigen values.

I am still very much learning this topic and can't see why my eigen vectors need to be of length 1, only then will putting them in a matrix and doing a similarity transform give me a diagonal matrix of the eigen values. So far in the course, this has never been pointed out or required for a successful diagonalisation of a matrix by similarity transform. I am guessing it is because in this case the matrix in question has complex elements.

Comment: making it orthonormal gives you the diagonalising matrix in one go.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is Hermitian, and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots, \lambda_n$ are distinct eigenvalues of $A$ then automatically all eigenvectors $v_i$ for $\lambda_i$ will be orthogonal (i.e. have inner product $0$) if they correspond to different eigenvalues. This is a standard theorem.

We can always multiply an eigenvector by a scalar and it will still be an eigenvector (for the same eigenvalue); eigenvectors for one eigenvalue form a linear subspace.

So we can make an orthogonal basis for each eigenspace and combine these to a full base (if we have $n$ eigenvectors and the matrix is $n \times n$) which is automatically orthogonal.

Then multiplying each vector $v$ by $\frac{1}{\|v\|}$ ensures the matrix $U$ of eigenvectors is orthonormal and $U^\dagger = U^{-1}$ which is easy in computations.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this, if i chose not to normalise my eigen values and do the computation, id find my final result to be the diagonal matrix of the eigen values multiplied the magnitude of each eigen vector in the eigen vector matrix.

Comment: @VishalJain yes, you’d get a scaled version of the diagonalising matrix.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, in the linked question I got confused because the comments and answers made me think that only upon scaling the eigen vectors down would I get a diagonal matrix. This fixes the confusion thanks.